# Writing a row with mutiple data into csv r

Tags: r, csv

So my dataframe looks like this

```
> df
 file_name        some_value               
 test.csv         12815415,5712365,12815383,13700109,12806007 

 write.csv(df,file="E:/output.csv",row.names = F)
```

And the resulting csv table looks like this

```
file_name        some_value   
test.csv         1.281545E+38
```

It seems that only the first entry in `some_value` is written into the csv, but where does the E+38 come from? Any advice to fix this, so that there are 5 entries under the column `some_value`?

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(file_name = structure(1L, .Label = "test.csv", class = 
"factor"), 
some_value = structure(1L, .Label = 
"12815415,5712365,12815383,13700109,12806007", class = "factor")), .Names = 
c("file_name", 
"some_value"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What is the type of the `some_value` column?

Comment: I don't think you'd have `E+38` if only the first value was considered. You'd have probably something like `E+7`.

Comment: The type is list.

Comment: I double checked the csv and the value is ended with`E+38` which is confusing to me.

Comment: It looks like the E+38 comes in because the comma separated values are entered in a single field in the csv file. If you open this in Excel, Excel is treating it like a single number where the commas are formatting (e.g. separating thousands from hundreds), so the number in scientific notation has 38 zeros. If you open the csv file in a text editor I think it would not look like this.  What is the structure of df?  Can you edit your post to include the output from `dput(df)`?  What would you like to be in the .csv file?

Comment: I see where the `E+38` comes from. The question has been updated with the output from `dput(df)`. The output in the csv file should be the same as the df shown, i.e. with five values under column `some_value`.

Comment: The data.frame created by the structure command you listed does not reproduce what you said your data.frame looks like.  Instead it has 5 rows each which has a label of "test.csv" and 5 different values for some_value.

Comment: Sorry about that confusion. The updated version should be correct now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this, you can start the field with a single quote.

```
df$some_value <- paste0("'",df$some_value) #Add a single quote to the beginning to indicate to Excel that it is a text field
```

Please note that the E+38 is really an Excel issue not an R issue.  It looks like the E+38 comes in because the comma separated values are entered in a single field in the csv file.  If you open this in Excel, Excel is treating it like a single number where the commas are formatting (e.g. separating thousands from hundreds), so the number in scientific notation has 38 zeros.  If you open the csv file in a text editor I think it would not look like this.

If I look at the file (without the apostrophe) in Notepad++
I see [image: File in text editor with all numbers and commas]

If I look at the same file in Excel, I see:[image]
Excel has interpreted some_value as a single number and the commas as formatting and shown that number in scientific notation.

Excel can be forced to treat the value as text by having a single quote before the numbers.

Comment: What does Excel have to do with this question?  I think you're right about the entire CSV string being treated as a single number.  But, your explanation is off.

Comment: I agree this is an issue of viewing the CSV output in Excel. Reading the CSV back into R with `df2 <- read.csv("E:/output.csv")` gives the original table, with the comma separated values in the some_value column.  And also, `as.numeric(gsub(',', '', df$some_value))` returns 1.281542e+38, the same value Excel is displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Just use at least one character as first element of some_values
e.g. s12815415,5712365,12815383,13700109,12806007 . Then export do consider some_values as a text and extract whole string

Answer (score 0):

Your are getting those kind of value because of the default visual property of MS excel (In windows). Open the .CSV file in Note pad (Right click and open with notepad) to get the exact output.